# What happens to a branch when the master is deleted?

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server, source-control

Say I create a branch of folder `Master` in my repository and make some commits to it.

I used TortoiseSVN's Create Branch command, which executes: `svn copy FROMURL TOURL` to create the branch on the server using the HEAD revision.

Later, the SVN administrator deletes the `Master` folder, but leaves my branch alone.

Since SVN branches are shallow copies, is my branch now corrupt, or does SVN smartly make a deep copy at the deletion of `Master`?

Comment: SVN isn't going to do anything you don't tell it to do.

Comment: @Ramhound That isn't very helpful. Are you saying my branch will become corrupted (as it will be a series of revisions to files that no longer exist) or not?

Comment: @NickUdell, the first question is what command did you issue to create the branch?

Comment: I used TortoiseSVN's Create Branch command, which executes: `svn copy FROMURL TOURL` to create the branch on the server.

Comment: You ask if SVN creates a deep copy upon the deletion of `Master`.  My response to that question is that SVN only does what you tell it to.  So if you delete `Master` before you perform a deep copy then you won't have a deep copy of `Master`.

Comment: I honestly don't know SVN enough to say for sure, but the description of "Cheap Copies" in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html) makes it sound like the SVN server handles the situation correctly.

Comment: Ok, I shall see if I can get access to my office's svn server to run a test on a new repository and I'll post an answer when I know more.

Answer (score 3):

Branch has a reference to a specific revision. Your branch should be safe. SVN uses references most of the time.